# Positive integer solutions to $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, quadratics, factoring, egyptian-fractions

I was looking at the equation $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} = \frac{c}{d}\,,$$ where $c$ and $d$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(c,d) = 1$.

> I was trying to find positive integer solutions to this equation for $a, b$, given any $c$ and $d$ that satisfy the above conditions. I was also trying to find whether there are additional requirements on $c$ and $d$ so that positive integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ can even exist.

I found that this equation simplifies to $abc - ad - bd = 0$ so that $abc = d(a+b)$.

Also, since the equation is equivalent to $a+b = ab(\frac{c}{d})$, this means $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic $dx^2-abcx+abd = 0$ since their product is $ab$ and their sum is $a+b = ab(\frac{c}{d})$.

However, after I analyzed the quadratic I just ended up with $a = a$ and $b = b$.

Any ideas on how to solve this further?

Again, I need to find all the conditions on the positive integers $c$ and $d$ (where $\gcd(c,d) = 1$) such that positive integer solutions for $a, b$ can exist. And then also find the positive integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ given that those conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Maybe, write $(ac-d)(bc-d)=d^2$.  So you need $ac-d=k$ and $bc-d=\dfrac{d^2}{k}$, for some divisor $k$ of $d^2$ such that $c\mid (d+k)$.  That is, $a=\dfrac{d+k}{c}$ and $b=\dfrac{d}{k}\,a=\dfrac{d}{k}\,\left(\dfrac{d+k}{c}\right)$.  So you also need that $ck\mid d(d+k)$.

Comment: Just realized: since $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime, the condition $ck\mid (d+k)$ means $ck\mid d+k$ (so $c\mid d+k$ is automatically implied). Hence, it suffices to find divisors $k$ of $d^2$ such that $ck\mid d+k$.

Comment: Given any $c$ and $d$ then I choose $c=3$ and $d=1$ and then there exists no solution. I may also choose $c$ and $d$ such that $\frac{c}{d}>2$ and there is still no solution.

Comment: Maybe your additional requirement should be $c\leq 2d$?

Comment: @MikaelHelin I guess as of right now it seems the conditions are $c \le 2d$ and that there must exist a divisor $k$ of $d^2$ such that $ck | d+k$

Comment: For given $c$ and $d$, $a$ and $b$ exist if and only if there exists a non-zero integer $n$ such that $(nc)^2-4nd$ is a perfect square. $a$ and $b$ then are the solutions for $x$ of $$x^2-ncx+nd=0$$Does this help?

Comment: @WolfgangKais Yeah that's a useful other way of looking at it.

Comment: I like the decomposition of $d^2$ introduced by @Batominovski. It can be expressed as follows:

A solution exists if and only if there is a decomposition $d^2=uv$ with integers $u$ and $v$ such that $c\mid d+u$ and $c\mid d+v$. The values of $a$ and $b$ are the results of the divisions ($\frac{d+u}{c}$ and $\frac{d+v}{c}$).

Answer (score 2):

Try some examples. I suggest researching Simon's Favorite Factoring trick, it helps with these types of questions. Asking on artofproblemsolving.com is a great idea, Simon is a real person who invented this factoring trick, and it's on that website.

I'll give you one example. Let's take $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{4}$. Note that $\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{1}{4}$. So, $4a+4b=ab$, meaning that $ab-4a-4b=0$, so $(a-4)(b-4)=16$. To solve this in the integers, just find the factor pairs of $16$ and solve for $a,b$

Hope this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is equivalent to (ac-d)(bc-d) = d^2. From there, you can find all the ways that two numbers multiply to d^2. If you have two numbers e and f that multiply to be d^2, then you can solve ac-d = e, bc-d = f individually. This stems from Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick that another person mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} = \frac{c}{d}\,,$

Above has solution:

$a=(3k-2)$

$b=(k-2)(3k-2)$

$c=(k-1)(3k-2)$

$d=(k-2)(3k-2)^2$

For k=5 we get:

$(a,b,c,d)=(13,39,52,507)$

Comment: The question clearly says $c$ and $d$ are given, we have to solve for $a$ and $b$.
If we were looking for any $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ then there are simpler solutions as $a=k$, $b=k$, $c=2$, $d=k$.

Comment: @JJAGMATH. Since "OP" has not provided a value for (c,d), I assumed a value (c,d)=[w(k-1), w^2(k-2)]. where w= (3k-2). In your comment even you are assuming value of (c,d)= (2,k).